# why is my Angular App Performance is low?

Tags: angular, optimization, angular-universal

Hi i work on  Angular app with service worker and Server Side Rendering
i [remove all timeout , make app module light and reduce the renderd html ] the app  reach about 50% on mobile my [google test speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.easyschools.org%2Far) and light house about 60%

> my app module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({
      appId: 'easy-school'
    }),
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CoreModule,
    NgxJsonLdModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    LazyLoadImagesModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserTransferStateModule,
    RouterModule,
    DirectiveSharedModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
      },
      isolate: true
    })
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NotFoundPageComponent,
    DownloadAppComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    NavBarComponent,
    AskQuestionComponent,
    AlertComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: environment.locale
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

> server module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'shell', component: AppShellComponent }
    ]),
    ModuleMapLoaderModule,


  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NgModuleFactoryLoader,
      useClass: ModuleMapNgFactoryLoader
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [AppShellComponent],
})
```

[image: page test screan]

Comment: How did you compile your application ?? I mean what command you used for compilation

Comment: "optimization": true,
              "extractCss": true,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "statsJson": true,

              "outputPath": "dist/browser/ar/",
              "baseHref": "/ar/",

              "fileReplacements": [{
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod-ar.ts"
              }]

Comment: I mean for building your application what command you use as i can see in google page speed it is showing me that you have multiple files like vendor.js , polyfills etc but if you build it properly then it will not have those files and it will reduce the size of the application as well. Try ( ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer) and then check your application size is reduced or not. and then apply light out test as well.

Comment: @SamarthSaxena i build using new angular config and i use build aot and build-optimize ng run easy-school:build:production-ar && ng run easy-school:build:production-en && ng run easy-school:server:production-ar && ng run easy-school:server:production-en